# Trying to get Vancouver-style (natbib) citations with [1-6] instead of [1;2;3;4;5;6] in the main text

Tags: citing, natbib

**Some background info**

So I'm trying to get citations and bibliography to look similar to the Vancouver style. The style, library, package is not so important (so I must not use natbib with Vancouver style in the environment; I'm open to using something else on Overleaf.com), just the appearance, which is basically: citations as numbers in parenthesis or square brackets (e.g. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqta6.png)) in the main text.

**The basic appearance I want and currently achieve:**

In the bibliography list I want the last names to be in full and appear first, followed by , then the first letter of the first names and the middle names. The sorting should be numerical in the text and the bibliography list.

**The issue:**

I'm having an issue with some citations appearing like this: `[1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6]` (see screenshot below), but I rather want it to appear like this `[1-6]`:
[image: Unwanted type of citation list]

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

**Behind the stage and elsewhere**

The text with the cite commands:

```
Many of the galaxy clusters in the observable universe have shown remarkable variations in their star formation rates \cite{Thompson2020GalaxyClusterDynamics, Johnson2021DarkMatterMapping, Wilson2019BlackHoleActivityInGalaxies, Patel2023StarFormationRates, Gomez2020GravitationalLensingEffects, Brown2022ExoplanetDiscoveryMethods}.
```

I'm using natbib like this and have the following documentclass:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{vancouver}
```

The bibliography looks like this:
[image: Bibliography]

In the bibliography list is like this:

```
@article{Thompson2020GalaxyClusterDynamics,
author = {Thompson, R. and Hamilton, D. and Jenkins, A.},
year = {2020},
title = {Dynamics of Galaxy Clusters and Their Impact on Star Formation},
journal = {Astrophysical Journal},
volume = {10},
pages = {100-115},
doi = {10.1000/astroj/2020.10.100}
}

@article{Johnson2021DarkMatterMapping,
author = {Johnson, M. and Davies, L. and Smith, K.},
year = {2021},
title = {Mapping Dark Matter in Distant Galaxy Clusters},
journal = {Journal of Cosmology and Astroparticle Physics},
volume = {15},
pages = {25-40},
doi = {10.1015/jcap.2021.15.25}
}

@article{Wilson2019BlackHoleActivityInGalaxies,
author = {Wilson, G. and Patel, N. and Singh, R.},
year = {2019},
title = {Activity of Supermassive Black Holes in Distant Galaxies},
journal = {Galactic Dynamics Review},
volume = {7},
pages = {55-70},
doi = {10.1020/gdr.2019.7.55}
}

@article{Patel2023StarFormationRates,
author = {Patel, S. and Wong, Y.},
year = {2023},
title = {Star Formation Rates in Expanding Universe},
journal = {International Journal of Astrophysics},
volume = {22},
pages = {200-215},
doi = {10.2030/ija.2023.22.200}
}

@article{Gomez2020GravitationalLensingEffects,
author = {Gomez, E. and Rodriguez, J. and Chen, M.},
year = {2020},
title = {Gravitational Lensing and Its Effects on Galaxy Perception},
journal = {Cosmic Phenomena Quarterly},
volume = {18},
pages = {150-165},
doi = {10.2080/cpq.2020.18.150}
}

@article{Brown2022ExoplanetDiscoveryMethods,
author = {Brown, T. and Kumar, P.},
year = {2022},
title = {Innovative Methods in Exoplanet Discovery},
journal = {Planetary Science Letters},
volume = {33},
pages = {78-92},
doi = {10.2234/psl.2022.33.78}
}
```

I'm using this environment/these settings on Overleaf.com:

[image: Environment]

Comment: The filename of your test file -- `main.tex` -- is irrelevant for the issue you wish to fix. Do please tell us, though, a few things that *are* important, such as the document class you employ and how the `cite` commands are formed.

Comment: @Mico: I think I added everything now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you change

```
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
```

to

```
\usepackage[square,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
```

to obtain a compressed citation call-out of the form `[1-6]`.